# How can I update the attributes of an HTML element inside a table cell?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which looks essentially like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <table class="ui table" id="items">
    <tbody>
      <tr data-toggle="fieldset-entry">
        <td><input id="items-0-quantity" name="items-0-quantity" type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input id="items-0-description" name="items-0-description" type="text" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using javascript, I'd like to have a button which adds a new row to the table, and I'd like the inputs in that new row to have `id="items-1-xxx"`, and `name="items-1-xxx`, i.e. where there's a `0` in the original row I'd like a `1` in the new row.

I can make a new table row by cloning the old one, but I have not figured out how to modify the `name` and `id` attributes of the input.
Here's a sketch of what I've tried:

```
function cloneRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("items");
  var original_row = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
  var new_row = original_row.cloneNode(true);

  // We have a new row and now we need to modify it as
  // described in the question. The only way I've found
  // is to grab the inner HTML:

  var cell_contents = original_row.cells[0].innerHTML;

  // Now we could do a bunch of string parsing and manipulations
  // to increment the 0 to a 1 and stuff the modified HTML into
  // new_row, but it seems there must be a better way.

  // Finally insert the new row into the table.
  original_row.parentNode.insertBefore(new_row, original_row.nextSibling);
  }
```

What is the right way to update the input elements' `id` and `name`?

Comment: Can't you just rebuild the row as a concatenation of strings like: "<td><input id="items-" + number + "quantity...</td>"?

Comment: @Propolys Yes, but I'm interested in whether or not there's a more data oriented way rather than parsing and manipulating strings.

Comment: loop through child elements and compare with if the id matches of that of input field and change input's value to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

You could just build a new `<td>` and assign `document.querySelectorAll('#items tr').length` as the `x` in `items-x-...`:

```js
function addItem() {
  var items = document.querySelector('#items')
    , itemcount = items.querySelectorAll('tr').length
    , newitemQuantityText = 'items-' + itemcount + '-quantity'
    , newitemDescriptionText = 'items-' + itemcount + '-description'
    , newitem = document.createElement('tr')
    , newitemQuantity = document.createElement('td')
    , newitemDescription = document.createElement('td')
    , newitemQuantityInput = document.createElement('input')
    , newitemDescriptionInput = document.createElement('input');
  
  newitemQuantityInput.id = newitemQuantityText;
  newitemQuantityInput.name = newitemQuantityText;
  newitemQuantity.appendChild(newitemQuantityInput);
  
  newitemDescriptionInput.id = newitemDescriptionText;
  newitemDescriptionInput.name = newitemDescriptionText;
  newitemDescription.appendChild(newitemDescriptionInput);
  
  newitem.appendChild(newitemQuantity);
  newitem.appendChild(newitemDescription);
  
  document.querySelector('#items').appendChild(newitem);
}

document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', addItem);
```

```html
<button id="add">add item</button>
<table id="items"></table>
```

However using good old `innerHTML` reads way better:

```js
function addItem() {
  var items = document.querySelector('#items')
    , itemcount = items.querySelectorAll('tr').length;
  
  items.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' +
    '<input id="item-' + itemcount + '-quantity" name="item-' + itemcount + '-quantity">' + 
    '</td><td>' +
    '<input id="item-' + itemcount + '-description" name="item-' + itemcount + '-description">' +
    '</td></tr>';
}

document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', addItem);
```

```html
<button id="add">add item</button>

<table id="items">
</table>
```

Comment: It's really too bad there isn't a data oriented way to do this. I posted another solution which just manually manipulates the HTML, but using string replacement via a regexp so that we don't have to hard code anything more than what we want to replace

Comment: There are tons of JavaScript frameworks that allow data oriented html generation. Start with good old [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) over outdated [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) to recent [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) and [Angular2](https://angular.io/). Data-orientation in vanilla HTML/JavaScript itself sounds too problem-specific for this language level.

Answer (score 0):

You can separately reconstruct the node itself by using

```
createAttribute()
createElement()
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ztb9gq3d/1/

Comment: I see how this could work, but we have to hard code the entire HTML string into the js function. That means that if we ever change the html in any way we'd have to change this function as well. This seems like it would make maintenance more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the data oriented approach the question asks for, but a reasonably simple solution is

```
numRows = table.rows.length;

// Use a regexp so we can replace all instances of the number
// corresponding to what is currently the last table row.
var re = new RegExp((numRows - 1).toString(), "g")

for (var i = 0; i <= originalRow.cells.length - 1; i++) {
  var originalHTML = originalRow.cells[i].innerHTML;
  var newHTML = originalHTML.replace(re, numRows.toString());
  newRow.cells[i].innerHTML = newHTML;
}
```

Obviously this only works if the number we replace doesn't exist elsewhere in the HTML string, so this is not a particularly good solution.
However, we could use a more complex regexp.

This solution does have the advantage that we don't need to hard-code anything except the parts we want to replace into the regexp.
Therefore, if the HTML in the table were to acquire additional parts in future development this solution will still work, up to the quality of the regexp as already mentioned.